# Run InOrder loop until size of tree is returned

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

How would I construct a loop that could run the InOrder operation until the size of the tree is returned. I tried to add while loops to either or both methods but it returns an error.

(Size is a global variable)

```
  public void inOrder(NodeWord current) {
    if(current != null) {
        inOrder(current.left);
        size++;
        inOrder(current.right); 
    }

}

public int size() {
    size = 0;
    NodeWord current = root;
    if(current != null) {
        inOrder(current);

    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: What error does it return?

Comment: You are not constructing a loop, you are constructing a recursive method. Are you looking for a loop instead of your recursive method?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your code shows a recursive solution (having some bugs), but you are asking about an iterative solution (loops). What are you looking for?

Comment: Also, what's wrong with the code you have now?